# How can I run homebrew program discs on unmodified Wii consoles?

Tags: wii, homebrew

I know that one can play backup games on any Wii console via burned discs, but is there a way to actually run homebrew programs on a Wii?

I am asking this because I have run across [GameCube Linux](http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/Main_Page) more than once, but most homebrew programs require using the Homebrew Channel, which must be installed on the internet through the Wii console, or via SD card. For Wii consoles that do not have this capability (specifically the Wii Mini), is it possible to run homebrew software discs that will work on Wii consoles without having to modify them? If so, can anyone show me which ones?